# Учебники по языкам

Tags: sql, ассемблер, javascript, php, perl

Приветствую товарищи IT-шники.
Немогли бы вы накидать в виде тематика/автор/название книги-учебники по SQL,php,perl,javascript, ну и по ассемблеру.
Причина по которой я не иду гуглить учебники в том что гугл не разделяет их на стоящие от пустышек.
Я не начинаю учить это с нуля, просто мне интересно прочитать рекомендуемые учебники, если я их уже не прочитал.
Заранее спасибо.

А еще такой вопрос:
Какой вы посоветуете софт использовать при освоении данных книг?

Answer (score 4):

**SQL**

SQL запросы для простых смертных (Майкл Дж. Хернандес, Джон Л. Вьескас) и 
SQL сборник рецептов (Энтони Молинаро)

еще читал "Изучаем SQL" (Алан Бьюли), но мне эта книга показалась совсем для начинающих.

**PHP**

Если уже знакомы с PHP, то можно выборочно посмотреть в 
"Профессиональное программирование на PHP" (Джордж Шлосснейгл)
и конечно же стоит почитать про ООП в PHP
PHP. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования. (Зандстра Мэтт), сейчас уже есть 3-е печатное издание, но не слишком отличается от 2-го, которое можно найти в сети.

Answer (score 2):

**Perl**
1) Изучаем Perl *(5-ое издание на русском. Правда сейчас уже есть и 6-ое издание, пока только на английском).*
2) Изучаем Perl глубже
3) Modern Perl (новая книга, только английском, в электронном виде - предоставляется бесплатно)
4) Программирование на Perl

Первые две - для новичков. Третью - лучше попозже прочитать. Четвертая - подробное руководство от создателя языка, там высвечиваются очень важные моменты, немного устарела, но уже готово следующее издание, в продажу выйдет осенью.

Answer (score 2):

**Perl**

Мне нравится вот эта подборка книг правда вся на английском:

1. Harvey M.Deitel / How to Program in Perl
2. Randal L. Schwartz, brian d foy, Tom Phoenix / Learning Perl 6th Edition
3. Chromantic / Modern Perl
4. Brian d foy / Mastering Perl
5. Damian Conway / Perl Best Practices

Также смотри на издание Oreilly очень хорошее: [oreilly.com/perl](http://oreilly.com/perl/)

Answer (score 2):

[Интерактивный учебник по SQL](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru).
Никакой дополнительный софт не нужен. Запросы к СУБД (SELECT) можно писать непосредственно в учебнике.

Comment: Да, и по-русски.

Answer (score 1):

по PHP после учебников тебе сюда частенько прийдеться заглядывать http://ru2.php.net/
так же, **читай паттерны программирования**... примеры книг не приведу ибо в сети всю необходимую информацию можно найти

писать кому в чем удобно, лично я работаю на Zend Studio 8

Answer (score 1):

Лично я очень уважаю [эту книгу](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781118013847/) по Perl. Не хочу навязывать свое мнение, но **Beginning Perl (Wrox)** обязательна, на мой взгляд, к прочтению.

Answer (score -1):

Литература по которой я в свое время изучал:

**Java:** 
1) Самоучитель Java Script - Вадим Дунаев (2 издания)
2) Java Script: Наглядный курс создания динамических WEB-страниц - Келли Л. Мэрдок
3) Java Script: Библия пользователя (5ое издание) - Денни Гудман, Майкл Моррисон
4) ВВЕДЕНИЕ В JAVASCRIPT - Стефан Кох
5) Java - Патрик Ноутон

**PHP**
1) Самоучитель.PHP - Д.Котеров
2) PHP 5 "Для чайников" - Джанет Валейд
3) PHP/MySQL для начинающих - Энди Харрис
4) PHP 5 в подлиннике - Дмитрий Котеров, Алексей Костарев
5) PHP уроки - Евгений Попов (сайт http://ruseller.com/)

**Всего понемногу:**
Креативный WEB-дизайн - Крис Джамса, Кондрат Кинг, Энди Андерсон
Самоучитель создание WEB-страниц и сайтов - Печников В.Н.

Вообще лучшим учебником является Google =)

Comment: Евгений Попов это конечно "вещь", правда если вы вообще абсолютный новичок и сами даже не сделали какой нибудь блог на бесплатном хостинге и вордпрессе, тогда можно и Попова посмотреть. А лучше всего читать и читать книги и практиковаться на своем пробном сайте.

Comment: у меня запущено несколько проектов, но всегда интересно узнать способы и методы которыми пользуются другие люди, Евгений иногда предлагает довольно рациональные, а иногда даже оригинальные решения в плане организации кода или реализации тех или иных процедур.
Согласен что на собственном опыте обучение проходит гораздо быстрее, также как и процесс понимания/усвоения проходит значительно лучше.
Представленная литература в свое время помогла мне разобраться со множеством недопониманий, поэтому не стоит ее недооценивать ни на каком уровне владения тематикой будь то "чайник" или "эксперт".

Comment: Ну по моему читать учебники такого рода и не практиковаться параллельно- бессмыслнно, потому как в голове мало что останется, в том числе понимания.  
Спасибо.

Comment: Таки нехорошо мешать в кучу Java и JavaScript

Comment: возможно просто неверно мой пост прочитал. пусть будет тоже и java :-)

Comment: да ну вас, злые вы =)

Comment: да норм все, не переживай )) яву я тоже хотел когда-нибуть потом... в далекой далекой галактике под пиво освоить %)